# Trying to add new custom tab at adminhtml_sales_order_view

Tags: adminhtml

I am working with Magento 1.9.2 and I am rewriting a custom extension trying to add new custom tab at the order view page in the admin panel.

This is the part in the config.xml pointing to the layout file:

```
<adminhtml>        
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <mageworx_ordersedit>
                <file>mageworx_ordersedit.xml</file>
            </mageworx_ordersedit>
        </updates>
    </layout>
    <events>
        <core_block_abstract_to_html_after>
            <observers>
                <mw_add_coupon_block>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>mageworx_ordersedit/observer</class>
                    <method>insertCouponBlock</method>
                </mw_add_coupon_block>
            </observers>
        </core_block_abstract_to_html_after>
    </events>
    <translate>
        <modules>
            <MageWorx_OrdersEdit>
                <files>
                    <default>MageWorx_OrdersEdit.csv</default>
                </files>
            </MageWorx_OrdersEdit>
        </modules>
    </translate>
</adminhtml>
```

Here is the content in /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/mageworx_ordersedit.xml

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_view>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addCss" ifconfig="mageworx_ordersmanagement/ordersedit/enabled"><name>css/mageworx/ordersedit/styles.css</name></action>

        <action method="addItem" ifconfig="mageworx_ordersmanagement/ordersedit/show_thumbnails"><type>js_css</type><name>mageworx/lightbox/css/lightbox.css</name><params/></action>
        <action method="addItem" ifconfig="mageworx_ordersmanagement/ordersedit/show_thumbnails"><type>js_css</type><name>mageworx/lightbox/css/lightbox-ie.css</name><params/><if>lt IE 8</if></action>
        <action method="addItem" ifconfig="mageworx_ordersmanagement/ordersedit/show_thumbnails"><type>js</type><name>mageworx/lightbox/js/lightbox.js</name><params/><if/></action>

        <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>mageworx/ordersedit/order_edit.js</name><params/><if/></action>

        <action method="addJs"><file>mage/adminhtml/product/composite/configure.js</file></action>
        <action method="addJs"><file>varien/configurable.js</file></action>
    </reference>

    <!--  Replace standard "Order History" block  -->
    <block type="mageworx_ordersedit/adminhtml_sales_order_history" name="order_history" template="mageworx/ordersedit/sales-order-view-history.phtml" />
    <reference name="order_tab_info">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>order_history</name></action>
        <action method="append"><block>order_history</block></action>
    </reference>
    <!--//  Replace standard "Order History" block  -->

    <reference name="order_items">
        <action method="addColumnRender" ifconfig="mageworx_ordersmanagement/ordersedit/show_thumbnails"><column>name</column><block>adminhtml/sales_items_column_name</block><template>mageworx/ordersedit/sales-items-column-name.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addColumnRender" ifconfig="mageworx_ordersmanagement/ordersedit/show_thumbnails"><column>name</column><block>adminhtml/sales_items_column_name_grouped</block><template>mageworx/ordersedit/sales-items-column-name.phtml</template><type>grouped</type></action>
    </reference>

    <reference name="content">
        <block type="mageworx_ordersedit/adminhtml_sales_order_edit_wrapper" name="oredrspro_js" template="mageworx/ordersedit/edit/wrapper.phtml" />
    </reference>

    <reference name="avanspayment">
        <action method="addTab">
            <name>mageworx_ordersedit_sales_order_edit_avanspayment</name>
             <block>mageworx_ordersedit/adminhtml_sales_order_edit_avanspayment</block>
        </action>
    </reference>        

</adminhtml_sales_order_view>
```

I have added this:

```
    <reference name="avanspayment">
        <action method="addTab">
            <name>mageworx_ordersedit_sales_order_edit_avanspayment</name>
             <block>mageworx_ordersedit/adminhtml_sales_order_edit_avanspayment</block>
        </action>
    </reference>
```

Then in: Mageworx/OrdersEdit/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/Edit/Avanspayment.php i have this:

```
<?php
class Mageworx_OrdersEdit_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Edit_Avanspayment
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template
    implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface
{
    protected $_chat = null;

    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setTemplate('mageworx/ordersedit/edit/avanspayment.phtml');
    }

    public function getTabLabel() {
        return $this->__('Add New Tab ');
    }

    public function getTabTitle() {
        return $this->__('Add New Tab Title');
    }

    public function canShowTab() {
        return true;
    }

    public function isHidden() {
        return false;
    }

    public function getOrder(){
        return Mage::registry('current_order');
    }
} 
?>
```

Then in: /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/mageworx/ordersedit/edit/avanspayment.phtml i have added this:

```
This is custom text to test!
```

The problem is that nothing appears as new additional tab in the order view page.

Where is my mistake? I see no errors on the orders view page but the tab is not showed either.

Comment: Make sure that you have `echo $this->getChildHtml('avanspayment')` or `echo $this->getChildHtml()` inside the reference block template.